# Invalidating parent model save through child before_save callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models, a Parent and a Child (as outlined below).  The child model has a `before_save` callback to handle some external logic, and if it encounters any errors, the callback invalidates that model being saved.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :child
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child

  validates :child, :presence => true
  validates_associated :child
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

  before_save :external_logic
  validates :parent, :presence => true

  def external_logic
    begin
      # Some logic
    rescue
      #Invalidate child model
      errors.add(:base, "external logic failed")
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

The problem that I'm running into is that the Child model instance is created as through the nested attributes of the Parent model.  When the external logic fails, I want the child model AND the parent model to not be saved, but instead the parent model is being saved on its own.  How can I achieve this?

Please note, I am aware of validation callbacks, but they are not suitable in this case.  The child model callback has to be a before_save.

**EDIT #1**

I already know about transactions, and don't consider someone telling me "hey, wrap it around a transaction externally" to be a valid response.  This question is explicitly about how to solve this issue through a before_save call.

Why I can't use validations on create - as mentioned in the comments, the external bit of logic needs to be guaranteed to run ONLY before a database save.  Validation calls can happen multiple times with or without altering the database record, so that's an inappropriate place to put this logic.

**EDIT #2**

Ok, apparently having the `before_save` return false does prevent the parent being saved.  I have verified that through the console and actually inspecting the database.  However, my rspec tests are telling me otherwise, which is just odd. In particular, this is failing:

```
describe "parent attributes hash" do
  it "creates new record" do
    parent = Parent.create(:name => "name", :child_attributes => {:name => "childname"})
    customer.persisted?.should be_false
  end
end
```

Could that be an rspec/factory_girl bit of weirdness?

**EDIT #3**

The test error is because I'm using transactional fixtures in Rspec.  That was leading to tests that incorrectly tell me that objects were being persisted in the database when they really weren't.

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

Comment: Can you please share the relevant controller code?

Comment: There is no controller code.  All of the functionality I need should be driven solely through the model, and function via saving models through the console.

Comment: Is there a specific reason this can't be runned as a validation (`validate :external_logic`)? You could have it both on validation and on save.

Comment: @jokklan its `validate :something` ...

Comment: @burninggramma your are right, sorry. It's now fixed :)

Comment: @burninggramma - the issue is that the function is being run multiple times, which it can only be run a maximum of once.  Adding more calls to the function is the opposite of what I want.

Comment: What database are you using? Does it support transactions? Is it MySQL with MyISAM?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL.  It supports transactions, but I don't know how I would wrap a transaction inside of a callback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay so your problem is with the [ActiveRecord::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) order.

As you can see on the linked page **first validation** is processed and **if validation was successful then before_save callbacks** are run. `before_save` is a place where you can assume every validation passed so you can manipulate a bit data or fill a custom attribute based on other attributes. Things like that.

So what you could do is just say for the `Child` model:
`validate :external_logic` and just remove the `before_save :external_logic` callback.

It's equivalent with what you want to do. When a `Parent` instance is created it will just error out if the `Child` object fails to validate, which will happen in your :external_logic validation method. This is a [custom validation method technique](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#custom-methods).

#### After OP update:

Still you can use `:validate` method. You can set it to only run on `create` with:
`validate :external_logic, :on => :create`.

If you are running into issue that you need this to run on `update` as well, that is the default behavior. Validations are run on .create and .update only.

**OR If** you want to stick to before_save:

`The whole callback chain is wrapped in a transaction. If any before callback method returns exactly false or raises an exception, the execution chain gets halted and a ROLLBACK is issued; after callbacks can only accomplish that by raising an exception.`

I see you did `return false` so it should work as expected. How do you use `Parent.create!` method? What are the arguments there?

Make sure you are using it like (supposing `.name` is an attribute of Parent and Child):

```
Parent.create!{
  :name => 'MyParent'
  # other attributes for Parent
  :child_attributes => { 
    :name => 'MyChild'
    # other attributes for Child
  } 
}
```

This way it both the Parent and Child object will be created in the same transaction, so if your `before_save` method returns false Parent object will be rolled back.

**OR**

If you cannot use this format you could just try using pure transactions ([doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html), [example in guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pessimistic-locking)):

```
Parent.transaction do
  p = Parent.create
  raise Exception if true # any condition
end
```

Anything you do inside of this transaction will be rolled back if there is an exception raised inside the block.

Comment: No, I understand callback order and how validations work.  The issue is that I can't have that function be called every time the model tries to validate - it needs to run only once, and only before a save happens.  Per the question I posted, I need the `before_save` callback to invalidate the parent model, not for additional validations to be run.

Comment: Returning `false` on a before_save in the child model doesn't invalidate the save of the parent model though - the parent model still saves, because its save calls happen before the child before_save callbacks even run.

Validating only on create is not an option - that calls actually runs twice when you tell the parent model to validate its children before save (so it has one valid? call by the parent and one by itself as the child).  Wrapping things in a transaction externally doesn't prevent the accidental implementation of a save outside of a transaction.

Comment: 1. It does invalidate, I just tested it right now. You got a parent object, but its not commited into the database. There is no `id` for the object. It's not persisted.  


2. `the parent model still saves, because its save calls happen before the child before_save callbacks even run` => this is just not true.
  

3. You can `Rails.logger.info` from the childs validation method, it is just in fact run once on .create.

Comment: I was incredibly skeptical of that comment, but I just spun up a new rails app, and you're right.  I'm trying to figure out what's going wrong in my tests and my implementation such that the `false` in my `before_save` isn't actually invalidating the parent.  Give me a few hours to get to the bottom of this.